# corona sdk fails to load images--- all of them

Tags: ios, sdk, lua, coronasdk

my code runs fine on simulator but when its on my device it wont load any of the images and on my log it says "failed to load ( image name)"????

I have all the images being called in the folder that "lua.main" is in.

heres the code---------------

```
--local physics = require("physics")
--physics.start()
--physics.setGravity( 0, 6 )
--system.activate( "multitoch" )
--physics.setDrawMode( "normal" )

centerX = display.contentCenterX
centerY = display.contentCenterY
--secCounted = 0
--W = display.contentWidth

--display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar )

--timer.performWithDelay( 1000, secCounter, 0 )

--local leftwall = display.newRect(0, 0, 1, 9000)
--local rightwall = display.newRect(W, 0, 1, 9000)
--local top = display.newRect(0, 0, 9000, 160)

--physics.addBody(leftwall, "static")
--physics.addBody(rightwall, "static")
--physics.addBody(top, "static")

local brickwall = display.newImage( "wall.png", centerX, centerY )

--local blackbar = display.newImage( "bar.png", centerX, 0 )

--local direct = display.newText( "Don't let the balloon touch", centerX, centerY, nil, 57         )
--local direct2 = display.newText( "the bottom or top.", centerX, centerY + 55, nil, 57 )
--local direct3 = display.newText ( "You exit through the sides!", centerX, centerY + 110,  nil, 57 )
--direct:setTextColor( 0, 0, 0 )
--direct2:setTextColor( 0, 0, 0 )
--direct3:setTextColor( 0, 0, 0 )

--local ground = display.newImage("floor.png", centerX, 1315 )
--physics.addBody( ground, "static", { friction = 1, bounce = .1 } )

--local function directions( event )
--  direct.text = ""
--  direct2.text = ""
--  direct3.text = ""
--end

--timer.performWithDelay( 9000, directions, 1 )

--local function addBalloon( event )
    --  local bballoon = display.newImage( "bbl.png", centerX, 300 )
    --  physics.addBody( bballoon, { friction = 3.0, bounce = .2 } )

    --function moveBalloon( event )
        --bballoon:applyLinearImpulse( 0, -3, event.x, event.y )
    --end

    --bballoon:addEventListener( "tap", moveBalloon )
--end

--timer.performWithDelay( 10000, addBalloon, 0 )

--local function secCounter( event )
    --  secCounted = secCounted + 1
    --  local blackbar = display.newImage( "bar.png", centerX, 0 )
    --  local myText = display.newText( secCounted, centerX, 50, nil, 100 )
--end

--timer.performWithDelay( 1000, secCounter, 0 )
```

------------------that was all of it.

ignore all of the commented parts i did that to see if it would just display the brick wall but it didnt!

I feel helpless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe your image has embedded ICC profile?

See Image Guidelines
http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newImage.html

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution and just thought I would share what I learned.

It turns out that in order to display a image it cant be renamed to a .png file if the image was edited. I had to leave the image as a .jpeg file

I hope that helped if anyone else was stuck!